# Laravel belongsTo with casts not working

Tags: laravel

I have model application and model attributes. 
In table applications, I have column: attributes (type json) In this columns I have ids of attributes. Example:

```
["5", "6", "7"]
```

This data in table applications in column `attributes`.

In model applications I writed relation:

```
protected $casts = [
    'attributes' => 'array',
];

public function attribute() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Attribute', 'attributes');
}
```

But I get only attribute with id `5`. But need get all atributes.
Why I get only one attribute? I tried and with `hasMany` I get the same result.

Comment: BelongsTo is for one to many.  If anything, it seems like you'd need BelongsToMany but I doubt Eloquent supports this without a pivot table.

Comment: yeah. Not working without a pivot table. I get error..

Comment: Pivot tables have their purpose.  It also gives you the ability to assign attributes to the relationship itself which can be very handy as your app grows.

Comment: No. I want write attributes in json columns))

Comment: Well, you can do whatever you want, but like I said, I doubt Eloquent is going to support something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a package with JSON relationships: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

You can create a many-to-many relationship like this:

```php
class Application extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = [
       'attributes' => 'array'
    ];

    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsToJson(Attribute::class, 'attributes');
    }
}

class Attribute extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function applications()
    {
       return $this->hasManyJson(Application::class, 'attributes');
    }
}
```